# Why PHP built-in web server should not be used on a public network?

Tags: php

I've been reading about PHP document in https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php and was wondering why `built-in web server should not be used on a public network?`

Is it because of the security issues?

If yes, is there any example or details about this?

Comment: In the warning at the top, it also says *It is not intended to be a full-featured web server*.  Is there any reason you need to use it?

Comment: @NigelRen, I don't know, that's why I ask the question here. I've no reason to use it. Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP
>   applications will stall if a request is blocked.

Also, it won't restart by itself if for a reason or another the process crashes.

In a pinch, it's a good tool, but it's definitely not be used on a public network.

Comment: Thanks, instead of closing my question without any answer, you're the only one trying to help by answering the question.

I really don't know .. That's why I ask the question here.

Closing the question without any answer wouldn't help at all.

Hopefully this community will get better in the future.